# request param not set in jsp request dispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm doing a request forward to another JSP from a JSP with some params in the request object.

JSP1

```
        session.invalidate();
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid user or password");

        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher; 
        requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/userlogin.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);;
```

userlogin.jsp

```
<%
if(null!=request.getAttribute("errorMessage"))
{ %>
<div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                <span> <%=request.getAttribute("errorMessage")%> </span>
            </div>

 <%   }
   else{
    System.out.println("no request");
  }
%>
```

Now Im not able to get the request parms from the request. Its always null in userlogin.jsp.
any help?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting null or any other exceptions ? Is "no request" being printed ?

Comment: @javaguy yes it prints "no request"

Answer (score 1):

Can you try without the statement
`session.invalidate();`

Comment: But the objective is to do session.invalidate(); first and then display the error message

Comment: The statement can be moved in the userlogin.jsp before displaying the message.

Answer (score 0):

Move session.invalidate() in userLogin.jsp because If you invalidate the session your parameter are not retrieve.